# PHP if isset $_GET any of the parameters if they are present in the POST request to a script

Tags: php, if-statement, parameters, get, isset

I have a strange case where a script should receive the values of 2 parameters every now and then. One of the parameters is geo and the other one is tids and I have to explode tids to 4 different variables for my use. I would like to setup a condition where geo parameter may be always present in the requested url and tids may not be. Would that be possible with OR operator "||"? For now I have

```
if (isset($_GET['tids']) || isset($_GET['geo'])) { 
    $tidsexplode=$_GET['tids'];
    $pieces=explode("separator", $tidsexplode);
    $country=$_GET['geo'];
    // do what I want with tids exploded $pieces and geo
}else{
    // take action as with tid1, tid2, tid3, tid4 and geo location being sent separately in different parameters and their other variables as usual
}
```

Basically I want to tell the script to act my way, if it is POSTed with parameters tids and geo and if not - process as usual for the separate tids 1, 2, 3 and 4 and geo location are sent in a different way with other parameters. If I try separating them with a comma (,) instead or OR operator (||) that means that all conditions have to be present, i.e. to have tids and geo always sent to the script, else the script won't process if only geo parameter is set. How do I set it to process if geo parameter present but tids may not be? The thing is that some other scripts may pass the data for tid1, 2, 3, 4, etc separately in different parameters tid1, tid2, tid3 and tid, and geo is extracted internally with other variable and from some other sources I get all the tids mixed with a separator together as one string and location as parameter geo. That is why I want to differentiate the cases within the same script without having to copy the same script with different name to distinct the cases and have separate APIs call different file because they have to process data differently.

Comment: Can you simplify the explanation?

Comment: If you simplify, (boil down) the explanation the Answer will probably be quite obvious to you

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Really too many inaccurate questions in one same text, sorry…

Comment: Your question is a massive wall of text. It would be easier to understand if you used paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say is if I have both do this, if i only have one, do the other? If so, this should do it, or at least point you in the right direction.

```
if (isset($_GET['tids']) && isset($_GET['geo'])) { 
     $tidsexplode=$_GET['tids'];
     $pieces=explode("separator", $tidsexplode);
     $country=$_GET['geo'];
     // do what I want with tids exploded $pieces and geo
}elseif (isset($_GET['tids']) && !isset($_GET['geo'])){
    // take action as with tid1, tid2, tid3, tid4 and geo location being sent separately in different parameters and their other variables as usual
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use **Nested IF Statements**. Try below code

```
if (isset($_GET['geo'])) {        
   $country=$_GET['geo'];
   if( isset($_GET['tids']) ){
      $tidsexplode=$_GET['tids'];
      $pieces=explode("separator", $tidsexplode);
   }      
}else{
  // take action as with tid1, tid2, tid3, tid4 and geo location being sent separately in different parameters and their other variables as usual
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (isset($_GET['tids']) || isset($_GET['geo']))
 {
   //run process for both
 }
 else 
 {
   function tids ($tid1=null, $tid2=null, $tid3=null, $tid4=null){/*run process*/}

  //split tids
  tids($tid1,$tid2,$tid3,$tid4); //call tids function
 }
```

The above function will substitute the values of `$tids`  with `null` if not available

Comment: I may give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did some extensive testing and looks like the code I wrote actually does the job and the error was someplace else. Thank you all for investing time and energy in helping me by answering! Much appreciated.